# Render openai-gym game to web

Tags: javascript, html, web, openai-gym

I want to render the openai games to web and record the action and frames. I don't know how should I implement this and I am not able to find any blog or data regarding this on Internet. The game should have minimal latency over web also. Please suggest some blogs or ideas.

Comment: I think you should set the render mode of gym to 'rgb_array' and save the ourput to redis or save it on the disk and then using js to get the data from redis or disk and render it on the webpage.

Comment: Hey Thanks! I did something similar, I used websockets and x-mixed-replace response to stream the frames(encoded to base64). But this does not works efficiently, it's lagging a lot. What should I try now?